# Error when running exe with wine : (c0000001)

Tags: wine

Whenever I run any exe, I get [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qh8W8.png). How can I fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

Install

```
sudo apt-get install wine32 q4wine wine-binfmt
```

After that is done, on terminal:

```
winecfg
```

Than restart your laptop and install your app. (32bit)